# How do I run an Intern test against iOS and android on BrowserStack?

Tags: intern, browserstack

What should I put in the environments block of the intern config file to test iOS and android?  According to https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities it should be as simple as

```
environments: [
    { browserName: "iPad" },
    { browserName: "android" }
],
```

However, that doesn't work.  Nor does this:

```
environments: [
    { os: "ios", browser: "iPad", device: "iPad 4th Gen" },
    { os: "android", browser: "Android" }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old so things have likely moved along.

But for completeness, it's possible to run mobile browsers with the following setup:

```
environments: [
   { platform: "MAC", browserName: "iPhone", device: "iPhone 5" }
]
```